# Redux Thunk Typescript cannot dispatch with Async

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I make a sample testing for redux-thunk (no react, only console app), the code is here:

```
interface IStartLoadAction extends Action<"START"> {
}

interface IEndLoadAction extends Action<"END"> {

}

type LoadActionTypes = IStartLoadAction | IEndLoadAction;

function startLoad(): LoadActionTypes {
    return {type: "START"};
}

function endLoad(): LoadActionTypes {
  return {type: "END"};
}
const loadReducer: Reducer<ILoadState | undefined, LoadActionTypes> = (
  state = initLoadState,
  action: LoadActionTypes) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "START":
          return {isLoading: !state.isLoading};
      case "END":
          return {isLoading: !state.isLoading};
      default:
          return {isLoading: false};
    }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loader: loadReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(Thunk));

const fetchData = (): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, ILoadState, null, AnyAction> => {
  return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>): Promise<void> => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
          dispatch(startLoad());
          console.log('start....');

          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(<some actions>);
          }, 2000);

          dispatch(endLoad());
          console.log('end....');
          resolve();
      });
  };
};
```

But when I call `store.dispatch(fetchData());`, It return an error:

> Argument of type 'ThunkAction, ILoadState, null,
>   AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.

How to let it work? Thanks (I wont use it in react env, server side only)

The sample of Redux official web site is "js", but not "ts", so I don't know how to translate it.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem - store.dispatch( actionCreator() ) causes error TS-2345. There are some examples in the net - first of all, none of them works (same problem), second, some of them use very non-transparent and incomprehensible type-fiddling without ever explaining reasons